# How to change the size of the "static application switcher"?

Tags: compiz

I changed the application switcher from unity's to Static Application switcher, using CompixConfig. See screenshot below.

I love it!!! but have 1 problem - the preview of the windows is a bit small.

**Is there a way to make the preview of the windows in the switcher bigger?** Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try "Shift Switcher", I don't settings for what you want in that plugin.

Comment: @userDepth I prefer static app switcher, because it shows all the apps in a single view - easier for me to switch between them.

Comment: *Scale* does that too, "Gnome like" it is already set on Unity, I think Super + W is the binding

Comment: If you ever did figure it out, I am also still interested in the answer. :-)